# Upload file in Hadoop using Java Api

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

Cannot connect to HDFS through java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        System.out.println("---143---");
        String localPath="/home/user1/Documents/hdfspract.txt";
        String uri="hdfs://172.16.32.139:9000";
        String hdfsDir="hdfs://172.16.32.139:9000/fifo_tbl";

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri),conf);

        fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path(localPath),new  Path(hdfsDir));
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8YDj.png)

When i tried to execute the above code, it gave me the below error:

> WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for
>   your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>       Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for
>   scheme "hdfs"
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3332)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3352)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
>         at com.Jambo.App.main(App.java:21)

Any other way to upload file in Hadoop using Java Api will be appreciated thank you

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
<artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
<artifactId>hadoop-yarn-common</artifactId>
<version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
<artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-common</artifactId>
<version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
<artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
<version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
<artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
<version>1.8.0_161</version>
<scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_161/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
<artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
<version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I highly recommend you edit your question to include the dependencies in the linked image. This makes it easy for people to read making it more likely your question will get answered. It also improves SEO.

Comment: @JamesJones maven dependencies included in the above question.